# Getting Android resource linking failed error on creating signed app bundle in android studio 4.1.1

Tags: android, dynamic, build, module, release

I am using app module and one dynamic module with my android project.

Getting below error while creating release build-

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{}],"original":"AAPT: error: invalid package ID 0x7e. Must be in the range 0x7f-0xff..\n\n ","tool":"AAPT"}

Comment: Any luck solving this?

Comment: I think my problem was that my base module and dynamic module had different minsdk versions. After making those the same, I was able to get more helpful error messages.

Comment: Do you get any solution ?